# Prove that $\int_{E}f = \int_{I}\int_{[\phi(x),\psi(x)]}f(x,y)dydx$ using Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> **Problem.** Let $E$ be a domain in the plane bounded by the continuous curves $y = \phi(x)$ and $y = \psi(x)$ for $x \in  I = [a,b]$, where $\phi(x), \psi(x)$. Prove that if $f$ is a Borel measurable, integrable function defined on $E$, then
>   $$\int_{E}f = \int_{I}\int_{[\phi(x),\psi(x)]}f(x,y)dydx.$$

**My attempt.** Use the Fubini's Theorem that says
$$\int_{I}\int_{[\phi(x),\psi(x)]}f(x,y)dydx = \int_{I \times [\phi(x),\psi(x)]}f(x,y)d(y \times x)$$
where $x \times y$ represents the product measure. But I could not relate $\int_{E}f$ with $\int_{I \times [\phi(x),\psi(x)]}f$. I believe that this is the main point of the question. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your equation at the end doesn't make sense as stated: In $I\times [\phi(x),\psi(x)]$, you haven't said what $x$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to apply Fubini's theorem in $\mathbb R^2.$ Recall that for any $g$ Borel measurable and integrable on $\mathbb R^2,$ we have,
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^2} g \ = \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} g(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y. $$
The key trick is to embed the information about $E$ into this function $g.$ So we set,
$$ g = \chi_E f. $$
Where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E \subset \mathbb R^2.$ By our assumptions $g$ is indeed Borel measurable and integrable, such that,
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^2} \chi_Ef = \int_E f = \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} \chi_E(x,y)f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y. $$
Now $(x,y) \in E$ if and only if $x \in I$ and $\varphi(x) \leq y \leq \psi(x).$ So we conclude that,
$$ \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} \chi_E(x,y)f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_I \int_{\psi(x)}^{\varphi(x)} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y, $$
from which the result follows.

Comment: Nice, I got it! Thank you!